# derivation of the triple product relation

Tags: multivariable-calculus

In the derivation of the triple product rule, starting with a differentiable $f$ function so that $f(x, y, z) = 0$:

$\left({\frac  {\partial x}{\partial y}}\right)_{z}\left({\frac  {\partial y}{\partial z}}\right)_{x}\left({\frac  {\partial z}{\partial x}}\right)_{y}=-1$

as found here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product_rule and on others textbook, it is supposed that one variable is hold constant `Suppose that we move along a curve with dz = 0, where the curve is parameterized by x.` 
I don't understand why this constancy condition is required if the identity must hold true for every $x,y,z$ and not only in the case of variable being constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will present a proof, similar to that on Wikipedia, with some clarifications. First, by a suitable rotation of the coordinate plane, we may assume at some point $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$, none of the partial derivatives vanishes and $f(x_0,y_0,z_0)=0$. Hence by the implicit function theorem, we may write $x=\phi(y,z),y=\psi(z,x),z=\xi(x,y)$ where $\phi,\psi,\xi$ are continuously differentiable in a neighborhood of $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$.

Now, by the mean value theorem of several variables, $\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x}=-\dfrac {f_x}{f_z}$. The other two partial derivatives appearing in the formula may be expressed similarly, and thus $\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial y}\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial z}\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x}=-1$.

Note that the partial derivatives are, by definition, evaluated by holding the third variable constant. Also, since the partial derivative of a multivariable function is defined locally, it suffices to prove the formula locally.

(MVT part)

By the mean value theorem, $f(x+h,y,z+k)-f(x,y,z)=hf_x(x+\phi h,y,z+\phi k)+kf_z(x+\phi h,y,z+\phi k)$ for some $0\lt \phi\lt 1.$ Within a sufficiently small neighborhood of $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ we have $f(x+h,y,z+k)=f(x,y,z)=0$, where $k=\xi(x+h,y)-\xi(x,y)$, so $\dfrac{f_x(x+\phi h,y,z+\phi k)}{f_z(x+\phi h,y,z+\phi k)}=-\dfrac kh$. Therefore, $\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x}=\lim_{(h,k)\to (0,0)}\dfrac kh=\lim_{(h,k)\to (0,0)}-\dfrac{f_x(x+\phi h,y,z+\phi k)}{f_z(x+\phi h,y,z+\phi k)}=\dfrac{f_x(x,y,z)}{f_z(x,y,z)}$.

Comment: can you show me how you derived the relation $\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x}=-\dfrac {f_x}{f_z}$ by using the mean value theorem?

Comment: edited the answer.

Comment: `Within a sufficiently small neighborhood of (x0,y0,z0) we have $F(x + h,y , z + k) = F(x, y ,z) = 0$`
This can only be true if $F$ were constant in a neighborhood of $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$, but we assume that none of the partial derivates of $F$ vanish there.

Comment: In that part z and z+k are given by the implicit function theorem, so $z=\xi(x,y), z+k=\xi(x+h,y)$

Comment: I have made an edit to make it more clear.